# Conversion between UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1:

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I found the following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559761/1180720)  in SO. Does this really work?

```
String xml = new String("áéíóúñ");
byte[] latin1 = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] utf8 = new String(latin1, "ISO-8859-1").getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I mean, `latin1` is UTF-8-encoded in the second line, but read als ISO-8859-1-encoded in the third? Can this ever work?

Not that I did not want to criticize the cited code, I am just confused since I ran into some legacy code that is very similar, that seems to work, and I cannot explain why.

EDIT: I guess in the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1559761/1180720), "UTF-8" in line 2 was just a TYPO. But I am not sure ...

EDIT2: After my initial posting, someone edited the code above and changed the 2nd line to `byte[] latin1 = xml.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");`. I don't know who did that and why he did it, but clearly this messed up pretty much. Sorry to all who saw the wrong version of the code. I don't know who edited it. The code above is correct now.

Comment: You’re doing this all wrong.  Do not decode.  doNOT getBYTES. Just compile with `java -encoding UTF-8` or whatever your true encoding is. Java has tolerable Unicode support, but the defaults work against you.

Comment: Your intuition is correct; line 2 is a typo or bug. The code transcodes a UTF-16 string to UTF-8, then pretends the data is ISO-8859-1 and transcodes it back to UTF-16 garbage. Then the corrupted string is  transcoded to UTF-8, resulting in more garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getBytes(Charset charset)` results in a byte array encoded using the `charset`, so latin1 is UTF-8 encoded.

Put `System.out.println(latin1.length);` as the third line and it will tell you that byte array length is 12. This means that it is really UTF-8 encoded.

`new String(latin1, "ISO-8859-1")` is incorrect because latin1 is UTF-8 encoded and you're telling to parse it as ISO-8859-1. That's why it produces a String made of 12 symbols of garbage: `Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃ±`.

When you're getting bytes from `Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃ±` using UTF-8 encoding it results in a 24 long byte array.

I hope everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are present in the both character encodings. It's just that [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) and [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout) uses each different byte representations of each character beyond the ASCII range.

If you used a character which is present in UTF-8, but not in ISO-8859-1, then it will of course fail.